# Adding a Header Option to Nickjs tab.open() function

Tags: javascript, node.js, chromium

I'm using NodeJs with NickJs browser emulation and am attempting to add a header when opening a page. I'm monitoring the request in Fiddler and see that the header is not being added.

How do I add the header?

Here's my current code:

```
var options = {headers: {"Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9"}}
await tab.open("https://www.google.com/", options)
```

Answer (score 1):

As per [the `open` method documentation](https://hub.phantombuster.com/v1/reference#nick-open), the optional `options` parameter works only with the CasperJS driver, being **ignored by the Chrome driver** (highlighted as bold in the documentation itself).